# Really simple command line SAX parser for XML files

Tags: xml, command-line, sax

I've used xmlstartlet to process XML files before. You can give it a simple comannd line and it will generate (internally) an XSLT template and apply that to an XML file.

However now I have a large XML file, so I really need to use SAX for this, not XSLT. Rather than write a simple programme to do this, I'm wondering if there is a more simplier way, to have a really simple SAX parser from the command line. You could give it a few options and it would whiz along your XML file and print out some structured data from it.

Answer (score 2):

Download Python and run it in interactive command line mode.

DOCS
http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html

EXAMPLE: 
[Showing progress while parsing a huge file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001871/showing-progress-of-pythons-xml-parser-when-loading-a-huge-file)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to extract and how (cause with sax you need to do everything on your own) - so the "configuration" is pretty complex hence there are afaik no commandline-tools, just programming languages that let you do sax.

How large is your xml? Maybe http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/ can help (also depending on the size of your xml.

Comment: Link is broken, but a snapshot of it is still usable, if weakly documented: https://github.com/clone/xml2 , https://web.archive.org/web/20160719191401/http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, I have 1.1G xml file.

Using xsltproc takes over 6G of memory, but **completes**.

I also tried saxon but it runs out of memory and **fails**.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

In the end we followed danglund 's advice and used Python, ATM.